# Filter by domain and subdomain separately in Google Apps email

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-apps-email

I want to setup a mail filter to filter my catchall email by their domain and subdomain only.

I've tried the obvious way of `to:example.com` for the primary domain and another filter `to:sub.example.com` for the subdomain, but the problem is that anything to the subdomain is tagged from the `to:example.com` filter as well and I want them completely separate.

So I tried `to:(example.com) -to:(sub.example.com)` for the primary and the reverse for the subdomain, but then for some reason nothing is being tagged in the subdomain even though the primary one is working correctly. Argh. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do the opposite of `to:(example.com) -to:(sub.example.com)`, you need to do `to:(sub.example.com)`. If you add `-to:(example.com)` you'll also exclude all the `sub.example.com` as well.

Comment: Thank you! Wow, so obvious now when you explained it like that. I had to do it in reverse since as you said, I was excluding the primary domain. Thank you! Just tested it and worked as expected! :)

Comment: Always happy to help.